# Django - form to create class based on type

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I've got an abstract model and a load of subclasses that inherit from it.

I can get a list of these subclasses but how would I go about putting them in a form so that the user can choose to create one of them?

So, for instance:-

```
class Abstract(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ImplA(Abstract):
    pass

class ImplB(Abstract):
    pass
```

I need a form which enables the user to choose to create either an instance of ImplA or an instance of ImplB.

Comment: Maybe create separate forms for each model?

Comment: So you want ur user to choose and create database columns ?

Comment: @xyres That could work - but I don't want to have to create a new form every time I add a new Impl to the code.

Comment: @Amar No, I want the user to be able to choose which type of object to create.

Comment: @bodger Are these model objects? if so then it means you are giving options to your user to create database columns

Comment: @Amar They'll be creating database rows. They choose which type of model object to create and the code creates one for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this as below

Firstly create a model to save the user inputs

```
SUBCLASSCHOICE = (
   ('ImplA', 'ImplA'),
   ('ImplB', 'ImplB'),
)
class UserTable(models.Model):
   abstract_class = models.CharField()
   sub_class = models.CharField(choices=SUBCLASSCHOICE)
```

You can now take data from UserTable and generate class dynamically like below

models.py 
    user_table = UserTable.objects.get()

```
local()[user_table.sub_class] = type(
    user_table.sub_class, #model class name
    (user_table.abstract_class ,),
)
```

Comment: Where is the form in this answer?